# event.constructor.name is not working in production in angular

Tags: angular

```html
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event, scrollContainer)"></router-outlet>
```

```
onActivate(e, scrollContainer) {
    scrollContainer.scrollTop = 0;
    
    if(e.constructor.name  === 'ReportsComponent'){
        e.PublishReport()
    }
}
```

Whenever the component class name is equal, it will call that component function. it works fine in local but it is not working on production.

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on the constructor name as it's generally not robust, because the code is minified in the build process so these names are lost. Moreover, it does not provide any solution for conflicting names.

Prefer using the class reference in your test, like this:

```
if (e instanceof ReportsComponent) {
    e.PublishReport()
}
```

It also makes you benefit from [TypeScript's control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) which will type `e` as a `ReportsComponent` inside the `if` code block.